# How is async&await different from a normal promise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

So we have this piece of code down here:

```
export const fetchPosts= async () =>{
   const response= await jsonPlaceholder.get('/posts');
    return {
        type:'FETCH_POSTS',
        payload:response
    };
};
```

I do understand that the get function is reaching to some API: (the jsonplaceholder file is below)

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'
});
```

why do we have to use the async and await syntax? From my limited understanding the get is itself a promise which makes it asynchronous and I do not see the benefit of the aync key word + the await key word. What do these two achieve?

Comment: It's just a different syntax for using normal promises. If you don't like `await` you can use `.then()`

Answer (score 0):

All async/await code can be converted into code using purely promises. Async/await is just syntatic sugar for promises, making the code more readable and more similar to synchronous code.